# How toc change class in element Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code:

```
<span id="id_1" ng-click="checkActivity(1)" class="item list-category-item  active ">Bga
</span>
```

How to change CSS class of element inside:

```
$scope.checkActivity = function(id){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your ng-click to `ng-click="checkActivity($event)"`
and also your function definition to

```
 $scope.checkActivity = function(evt) {
      angular.element(evt.currentTarget).addClass('myClass');
    };
```

Working demo [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/qRQAgKmrXIoO6VRglP7K?p=preview)

Comment: You're using AngularJS, so this is not the best approach in this case. As other users suggested you should use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) as described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-class` to add classes dynamically.

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.checkActivity = function(id){
  $scope.id = id
}
})
```

```css
.sample{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <span id="id_1" ng-click="checkActivity(1)" class="item list-category-item  active" ng-class="{'sample':id}">Bga
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I need modify element as Jquery

Comment: I tried to pass this in `ng-click="func(this)"` after in function tried: `angular.element(this).addClass("active");` it does not work

Comment: Your example will select all element by on click

Comment: why are using jquery and angular. just adapt to angular and remove the jquery

Comment: So, because I need to change only one element by that was click, for that I tried to get `this` nd modify

Comment: use ng repeat and loop the element

Comment: For what? How? dddd

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive to change the class of the element.